# Read one worksheet and load data into another one but not just as a reference

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a list of equipment assets and attributes which is a raw data dump from a database. Among attributes like equipment status (like running, in standby etc.) or Oil level it also includes things like headers and place holders as separate record line. So that is what I am working with in terms of data.

What I would like to do with this data is populate another sheet with that information by selecting it based on a partial text line among other criteria. Here is a sample of what a cell I am checking on would contain.

```
"\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\BU-1002\P-1866A"
```

What I would be checking for would be "DE-OILING D" portion of that text line. This can include hundreds of records and by pulling the records with only that partial text I won't pull the other hundreds of records that I don't need.

Now I am hoping this is possible with a function. I know that I can count the number of these records that are in that data list with a `COUNTSIF` statement (This formula works for me "=COUNTIF('DBASE SHEET'!B:B,A4)"). So I know that it can be detected but for the life of me I can't figure out how to pull the other data fields by checking for the "De-Oiling D" text as the conditional argument and then reference the other data based on that criteria.

I have tried `index()`, `indirect()`, and `vlookup()` and it is either something completely different or maybe a combo of these functions. Either way I cannot seem to get the formula to work.

Now here is the other wrinkle. Once I have detected said record that I want to pull over to the new worksheet I want to be able to create a list of the new data but without a whole bunch of blank lines in it.

Record sample using `|` as cell separators:

```
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING C\P-1370 | NULL            |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING C\P-1370 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING C\P-1370 | OIL LEVEL       |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING C\P-1370 | SUCTION PRESSURE|
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1470 | NULL            |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1470 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1470 | OIL LEVEL       |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1570 | NULL            |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1570 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D\P-1570 | OIL LEVEL       |
```

What I would like to have as output is the following without having spaces or any of that stuff:

```
|DE-OILING C | P-1370 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|DE-OILING C | P-1370 | OIL LEVEL       |
|DE-OILING C | P-1370 | SUCTION PRESSURE|
|DE-OILING D | P-1470 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|DE-OILING D | P-1470 | OIL LEVEL       |
|DE-OILING D | P-1570 | RUNNING STATUS  |
|DE-OILING D | P-1570 | OIL LEVEL       |
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the input data and screenshot of desired output?

Comment: Sadly this was my first post and apparently cannot add pictures. :(

Comment: This is a sample of the data in the cell I am checking on. A4 contains \Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D*

Comment: Reworded for clarity hopefully.

Comment: You say “… I would like to … populate another sheet with … information by selecting it based on a partial text line ….  What I would be checking for would be "DE-OILING D" portion of that text line.  … by pulling the records with only that partial text I won't pull the … records that I don’t need.”  So why does your sample output include lines that don’t contain “DE-OILING D”?

Comment: And what about the lines that contain "NULL" in the last column? You want to exclude them?

Comment: Scott: I was just trying to show what the output can be like as I may only be looking for the De-OIL C but I could also be looking for DE-OIL D and other "sections".  David: Yes I don't want any of the lines that contain 'NULL'. These are talking about container descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with considering the COUNTIFS() statement. Treat the text string like you would when comparing numbers, using > and < qualifiers to check whether each string begins with the section you're looking for.

```
=COUNTIFS('DBASE SHEET'!B:B,">"&A4,'DBASE SHEET'!B:B,"<"&A5)
```

where A4 contains your

```
"\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING D"
```

and A5 contains

```
"\Hierarchy\P2 PROCESS DE-OIL\DE-OIL\DE-OILING E"
```

If you need a dynamic formula to auto-populate A5, try

```
=LEFT(A4,LEN(A4)-1)&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(A4,1))+1)
```